# How to inherit some slots with its validity and prototype in R S4 class?

Tags: r, inheritance, partial

In the following code I have made three classes: A, B, and B1. What I want to do is to make A as is, then make B by inheriting from A like in B1 but would look like B, so not inheriting everything from A.

That is to say that I want to inherit only the slot x from A in B with its validity and prototype but should not have the other slots of A. Also in B I have one added slot b and it should come after the inherited slot x from A not before.

```
.A <- setClass(
  Class='A',
  slots=c(x='character', a1='numeric', a2='logical'),
  validity=function(object) if(length(object@x)!=1) return('x should be character of length 1'),
  prototype=list(x='X', a1=c(1, 0.5, 0), a2=c(T, F, T))
)


.B <- setClass(
  Class='B',
  slots=c(x='character', b='integer'),
  validity=function(object) if(length(object@x)!=1) return('x should be character of length 1'),
  prototype=list(x='X', b=c(1L, 7L, 9L))
)


.B1 <- setClass(
  Class='B1',
  contains='A',
  slots=c(b='integer'),
  prototype=list(b=c(1L, 7L, 9L))
)
```

Comment: Hi, does anyone have the answer?